# How to apply transition only on transform: translateX()?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations, css-transitions

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(255, 99, 99);
}
div:hover{
  transform: translateX(100px) rotateZ(45deg);
  transition: transform 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hover on me.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to apply transition on only `translateX()`, not on `rotateZ()`.

Something like **`transition: translateX 1s;`**. Is there any way to do it? (Chrome browser).

Comment: No, that is not directly possible. You can only transition on properties - `transform` _is_ the property here, and `translateX(100px) rotateZ(45deg)` is its value. You will have to use two nested elements for this, so that you can apply the translation and the rotation separately - and then you can transition transform on only one of those elements.

Comment: So do you want the rotation to be applied instantly when hovered and *then* start a transition for the transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use individual transform but pay attention to the browser support as it's a new feature

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(255, 99, 99);
  transition: translate 2s;
}
body:hover div{
  translate: 100px 0;
  rotate: 45deg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hover on me.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you refer to "individual transform"? I can't find it on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=individual%20transform). Nice feature, never knew about this!

Comment: @SigurdMazanti they are classic properties, all you have to do is to search for each one individually

Comment: Couldn't find much about browser support, but according to web.dev, [individual transforms are supported in all modern browsers](https://web.dev/css-individual-transform-properties/#the-individual-transform-properties)

Comment: Wow. I never knew about this. Is it new feture?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a hacky way to achieve this using `keyframes`. Note that you will need to move the cursor as the div moves, to maintain the hover state.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(255, 99, 99);
}

div:hover {
  animation: onlyTranslate 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes onlyTranslate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  1% {
    transform: translateX(0px) rotateZ(45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px) rotateZ(45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover on me.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using keyframes animation instead of transition.
Place rotateZ() in the % range where it should fire.
Otherwise, you can try JS implementation, tell me if you need a sample.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(255, 99, 99);
}
div:hover {
  animation: move 2s normal forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes move {
    0%   {
      transform: translateX(0px) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    95% {
      transform: translateX(100px) rotateZ(0deg);    
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100px) rotateZ(45deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hover on me.</div>
</body>
</html>
```